# Cyclic receiving items

Tags: php, mysql

groups database structure

id | parent_id | name

sample data

```
   id | parent_id | name
    3 | 2         | group1
    4 | 3         | group2
    5 | 4         | group3
    6 | 4         | group4
```

the desired result

```
3, 4, 5, 6   ( -  these groups have group1 )
```

Code

```
$CurrentGroup = 3;
$query = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id = ' . $CurrentGroup);
// I get IDS for subgroups of Group(3)
foreach ($query as $value) $ids[] = $value['id']; 
// just need to get all subgroups $ids used and their subgroups
```

Need to get a list of all subgroups and their subgroups in the database by adding subgroups added parent_id (Id group which adds subgroup). Subgroups can be at sub